# New entry in dataframe is deleting the previous entry in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

In this code, I'm trying to generate water level data for a for every minute for a whole day then storing that data to pandas data frame but when I try to do so the new data in data frame deletes the previous one and at last in the data frame there is only one value left.

```py
filling = 10/6
emptyrate = 5/6
current_level = 60
start_date = '11/01/01'
end_date = '11/02/01'
start = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%y/%d/%m")
end = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%y/%d/%m")

#generating random values for determining the state of the motor
now = start
workdate = now.date()
nowtime = now.time()

endt = end
ktime = end  

#generating random level of water in the tank 
print(current_level)

def fill():
    global now
    global workdate
    global nowtime
    global ktime
    global current_level
    global flag
   
    while x == 'on' and current_level <= 450:
        Data = {'time':now,'status':x,'level':current_level}
        df = pd.DataFrame(Data, index = [0])
       
        print(current_level)  
        current_level += filling
        current_level = round(current_level,2)
        now = now + timedelta(minutes = 1)
        nowtime = now.time()
        workdate = now.date

        if now == ktime:
            Data = {'time':now,'status':'on','level':current_level}
            df = pd.DataFrame(Data,index = [0])
            print("true")
            flag = 'red'
            break
```

Comment: When you do `df=pd.DataFrame(Data,index=[0])` you are recreating `df` every time. Try `df.loc[len(df)] = data`

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed overwriting the dataframe with each `df = ...` assignment inside the `while` loop. Instead of the solution suggested by @Aryerez, for a scalable approach that avoids excessive calls of `pd.DataFrame`, you could collect the data in lists and only create a dataframe once, in the end.

Specifically, replace this part:

```py
    while x == 'on' and current_level <= 450:
        Data = {'time':now,'status':x,'level':current_level}
        df = pd.DataFrame(Data, index = [0])
```

with this:

```py
    times = []
    states = []
    levels = []

    while x == 'on' and current_level <= 450:
        times.append(now)
        states.append(x)
        levels.append(current_level)
```

Then, at the end of the function, after the `while` loop, add this:

```py
    data = {'time': times, 'status': states, 'level': levels}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```